# HTTP Status 404 - (projectName)/faces/Login.xhtml - the requested resource not available

Tags: jsf, tomcat8

I am developing some software but I am facing this issue

```
HTTP Status 404 - (projectName)/faces/Login.xhtml - the requested resource not available
```

In my office laptop it is working fine, but in my home laptop I don't know what's the problem behind this.

I tried to clear, rebuild project again and again but the problem is not going.

My other projects are running good.

here is my `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>EMSLoginAndAttendanceModule</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Login.xhtml</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <session-config> 
   <session-timeout>45</session-timeout> 
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

this is the structure of my `Login.xhtml` file

```
WebContent
  |_META-INF
  |_WEB-INF
    |_faces-config.xml
    |_web.xml
  |_Login.xhtml
```

Comment: what is your servlet code. what framework do you used (Spring MVC , ...) ??

Comment: jsf, currently i have bean class and xhtml

Comment: @M2E67: Look at the tags... JSF... and why the question about servlet code?

Comment: @Malikyawar: Tomcat 8 can **never** be java-ee, java-se is also not related. And you can remove all the jsf related config in your web.xml and use the defaults (since you seem to be using recent versions of all specs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was because no `libraries` were included in the `Deployment Assembly` so after adding that error was resolved.

**Steps to resolve the error:**

`properties` of  `project` than `Deployment Assembly` 
click on `Add` from right pane than select `Java Build path Entries`

From there I added all my `libs` and error gone away.

Comment: May I suggest using a dependency management tool? Will save you lots of work when using more and more external libraries

Comment: yeah maven is the best thing for this,  you can suggest me others if you have in your mind.